# Get current location of the user on Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app which uses users current location on launch. I have been using `GeoLocation` plugin until now. But the plugin is giving me timeout error on many devices ( and there is nothing wrong with the code, it just refuse to work with chrome webview implementation in some phones ).

I am looking for some other plugin which can help me quickly get the location. I tried `Background-location` plugin but it is slow. Tried `GoogleMaps` plugin, it is fast but I have to load the map to view if I want to get the current location.

Does anyone have any possible solution?

Comment: got any solution ...plz post it here